# How do I use get_the_tags on a Wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I've added tags to my Wordpress pages (which are working fine) but I'm trying to list them on the page.

The idea is to get all the tags a particular page (not post) has and format them. What I'm getting is either 2 random (unrelated) tags, or the entire tag list. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
$relatedArea = the_slug(false); //gets the slug of the page - false represses the echo statement

$allTags = get_tags(); //gets all the tags
$areasOfLaw = array(); //starts the array

// check if the tag is included on the page
foreach ($allTags as $tag) {
  if(has_tag($relatedArea)) {
    $areasOfLaw[] = $tag; //add to the array
  }
}
```

Tried `$areasOfLaw = get_the_tags()` but it gave me random tags.

Here's the formatting, but I'm pretty sure it's working correctly.

```
foreach($areasOfLaw as $tag){
    echo '
        <a href="'.get_site_url().'/services/'.$tag->slug.'">
        <li>'.$tag->name.'
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right action"></span>
        </li></a>';
    }
```

**edit: this is my tag support included in the functions file**

```
// add tag support to pages
function tags_support_all() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page');
}

// ensure all tags are included in queries
function tags_support_query($wp_query) {
    if ($wp_query->get('tag')) $wp_query->set('post_type', 'any');
}

// tag hooks
add_action('init', 'tags_support_all');
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tags_support_query');
```

Comment: How you are using `get_the_tags()` function, inside the loop ?

Comment: I had been using it as `$areasOfLaw = get_the_tags();` but it wasn't returning what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_the_tags()` function returns all the tags associated with a `post` and if you use it inside the loop then you may use it like this:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
```

But if you use it outside of the loop then you have to supply the `ID` of the post for which you want to retrieve that tags, for example to get all the tags of post whose `ID` is `10`:

```
$tags = get_the_tags(10);
```

Now you can loop `$tags` like this:

```
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    echo $tag->name . ' ';
}
```

Read more on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags).

Comment: Hmm. I'm inside the loop, but for whatever reason the ID isn't getting passed correctly. When I use `get_the_tags(46)` (for example) then I am getting the correct tags. Using `the_ID()` returns 1, even when the page is 46.

This helped me find the solution: My id wasn't being returned correctly.

Comment: If you are inside the loop (loop of `post`) then you may use `get_the_tags($post->ID)` to explicitly set the `ID` of current post.

Answer (score 0):

@Sheikh Heera pointed me in the right direction.

Turned out even though `$areasOfLaw` was in the loop, my page id wasn't returning correctly.

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
$page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
$areasOfLaw = get_the_tags($page_id);
```